# Is there a bug in this

Tags: python, blackjack

I am totally new to programming. This is my second program so far. I have two challenges in this code.

1. For most of the initial runs this works fine in pycharm but after few runs this gives an error message like below. The bloc of code which is causing this error seems to be executing in the beginning and then its giving this error. Please someone help me with this.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Practice\100 Days of coding\Day 11\Black Jack.py", line 81, in <module>
    play_game()
  File "D:\Python\Practice\100 Days of coding\Day 11\Black Jack.py", line 70, in play_game
    while comp_score < 17:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Challenge 2: I have overserved that the cards stored for computer alter occasionally. I am unable to figure out why. Please help.

```
    import random
    
    def play_game():
    
        def deal_card():
            cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
            card = random.choice(cards)
            return card
    
    
        def calculate_score(card_list):
            if sum(card_list) == 21:
                if len(card_list) == 2:
                    return 0
    
            else:
                if 11 in card_list and sum(card_list) > 21:
                    card_list.remove(11)
                    card_list.append(1)
                return sum(card_list)
    
        def game_result():
            print(f"Computer cards are {comp_cards} and computer score is {comp_score}.")
            print(f"Your cards are {user_cards} and score is {user_score}.")
            if comp_score == user_score:
                print("Your scores are equal. Match Draw.")
            elif user_score == 0:
                print("Yay Black Jack! You win!")
            elif comp_score == 0:
                print("Computer has Black Jack. You loose.")
            elif user_score > 21:
                print("You went over 21. You loose.")
            elif comp_score > 21:
                print("Computer score went over 21. You win!")
            elif user_score > comp_score:
                print("You won!")
            else:
                print(f"Computer score {comp_score} is greater than your score {user_score}.\n You loose.")
    
        print("Welcome to BlackJack!")
        comp_cards = []
        user_cards = []
    
        for _ in range(2):
            comp_cards.append(deal_card())
            user_cards.append(deal_card())
    
        user_score = calculate_score(user_cards)
    
        print(f"Computer cards {comp_cards}")
        print(f"Your cards are {user_cards} and your score is: {user_score}")
    
        pass_ = False
    
        while pass_ == False:
            deal_a_new_card = input("Type 'y' to get another card and 'n' to pass.  : ")
    
            if deal_a_new_card == "y":
                user_cards.append(deal_card())
                user_score = calculate_score(user_cards)
            else:
                pass_ = True
    
            if user_score > 21:
                pass_ = True
            print(f"Your cards are {user_cards} and your score is: {user_score}")
    
        comp_score = calculate_score(comp_cards)
    
        while comp_score < 17:
            comp_cards.append(deal_card())
            comp_score = calculate_score(comp_cards)
    
        game_result()
    
    
    play_again = 'y'
    
    while play_again == "y":
    
        play_game()
        play_again = input("\nWould you like to play again? Enter 'y' to play.    : ")
```

Comment: you are defining function inside a function but I feel like you are trying to create an object.

Comment: instead of giving a  while loop for playing the game again I just made that entire block as a function and then I can give a while loop with the function called inside it. Seemed more legible..

Comment: The error message would pop-up when `sum(card_list) == 21` and `len(card_list)`  is not 2. In that case `calculate_score` would return `None`

Comment: `calculate_score` returns `None` (in the `if` block), when the number of cards is bigger than 2.

Comment: Thanks Maurice for your answer. Changed my code to
def calculate_score(card_list):
                if sum(card_list) == 21:
                    if len(card_list) == 2:
                        return 0
                    else:
                        return sum(card_list)

                else:
                    if 11 in card_list and sum(card_list) > 21:
                        card_list.remove(11)
                        card_list.append(1)
                    return sum(card_list)

Comment: Here is an example of the second challenge I mentioned in question.
Welcome to BlackJack!
Computer cards [11, 10]
Your cards are [8, 4] and your score is: 12
Type 'y' to get another card and 'n' to pass.  : y
Your cards are [8, 4, 10] and your score is: 22
Computer cards are [10, 8, 1] and computer score is 19.
Your cards are [8, 4, 10] and score is 22.
You went over 21. You loose.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because there are some circunstances where calculate_score() is not returning any value.

You are only returning a value when 'the sum isn't 21' or 'when it's equal to 21 AND there are 2 cards'. But you should also return value if you got a sum of 21 in more than 2 cards.

So you need to include in line 13th of your code:

```
 if sum(card_list) == 21:   
   if len(card_list) == 2:   
     return 0  
   #From here on:
   else:
     return another_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need to put the entire fuction in play_game() instead you can start it at cards_list you defined and adjusted the rest of the code.